# Per-Application Color Management under GNOME3

Tags: color, color-management, display-calibration, linux

I have recently used DispcalGUI and a Spyder4 to calibrate my monitor. I have selected the resulting calibration profile with the GNOME setting manager. However, instead of making my workflow more transparent, now different applications display colors differently.

Here is an example screenshot showing chromium, EOG, and nautilus renderings:

[image]

The general rule seems to be that all programs except EOG display saturated images whereas EOG displays desaturated and green tinted alternatives.
In GIMP, if I go under "Edit" > "Preferences" > "Color Management" I find a checkbox called "Try to use system monitor profile". If I check that, the colors in GIMP also become more desaturated.

I have 2 questions:

- How can I make chromium and nautilus display the colors correctly?
- Why does color profiling have to be set at the application level when I am already setting it in the GNOME settings manager? Selecting a profile there already changes my colors - so why on earth is there a separate "application level" for profiling?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I assign a profile to my monitor in Gnome Color Manager, should I also enable that profile in Gimp?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14585/if-i-assign-a-profile-to-my-monitor-in-gnome-color-manager-should-i-also-enable)

Comment: No, it is not. I am already aware that I have to enable color management in GIMP as well. My questions are: why? and how do I do the same for nautilus and chromium?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make chromium and nautilus display the colors correctly?

As I know it's still impossible to make chromium use color profiles. Workaround is using Firefox. I don't know about nautilus. Perhaps it doesn't support color profiling.

> Why does color profiling have to be set at the application level when I am already setting it in the GNOME settings manager? Selecting a profile there already changes my colors - so why on earth is there a separate "application level" for profiling?

GNOME settings manager only provides a way programs can get a system color profile, it can't make programs use that color profile. Moreover not every program is able to get a profile from GNOME settings manager.